# Why does a decision variable domain declaration not work in Pyomo v5.7 that worked with v5.6.9

Tags: pyomo

I have a decision variable declaration that does not work in Pyomo 5.7 that did work in 5.6.9.

The line in question is part of building a (concrete) model:

```
    model.v = pe.Var(within = pe.RealSet)    #pe = pyomo.environ
```

This ran fine when I had Pyomo version 5.6.9, but now gives errors described below in the provided code block.

To run with 5.7 I had to drop the within statement so I am left with:

```
    model.v = pe.Var()
```

What is the reasoning for no longer supporting an explicit statement that the domain includes all reals?

When running with the original statement with Pyomo 5.7, I get this error (CPython 3.7.1 on Windows 10):

```
    ERROR: Constructing component 'v' from data=None failed: TypeError: __new__()
    takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "runscript.py", line 216, in <module>
        payoff_matrix = my_matrix
      File "C:\Users\myusername\Documents\modelbuildscript.py", line 24, in __init__
        model.v = pe.Var(within = pe.RealSet)
      File "C:\EngTools\Anaconda3\2018.12\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\block.py", line 543, in __setattr__
        self.add_component(name, val)
      File "C:\EngTools\Anaconda3\2018.12\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\block.py", line 1081, in add_component
        val.construct(data)
      File "C:\EngTools\Anaconda3\2018.12\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\var.py", line 613, in construct
        self._initialize_members((None,))
      File "C:\EngTools\Anaconda3\2018.12\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\var.py", line 682, in_initialize_members
        self.domain = self._domain_init_rule(self._parent())
    TypeError: __new__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you should use

```py
model.v = pe.Var(within=pe.Reals)
```

The slightly longer answer is that the Pyomo global sets (`Reals`, `NonNegativeReals`, `Integers`, `PositiveIntegers`, `Binary`, etc.) were originally defined using their own class hierarchy independent of the `Set` and `RangeSet` components.  Unfortunately, that led to numerous problems (correctly detecting discrete sets, performing set operations using global sets, etc).  Pyomo 5.7 switched to a new rewrite of the `Set` / `RangeSet` components that among numerous other bug fixes moved to a new paradigm where *all* sets in Pyomo were either `Set` or `RangeSet` components (even global sets).  We put in a backwards compatibility layer that caught all the legacy uses of the `RealSet` class in the test suite, but your use case (while it worked) was not a documented / tested case.  [PR 1619](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/pull/1619) will restore this functionality (likely will be included in Pyomo 5.7.1), and adds an official deprecation warning for use of `RealSet`.

Comment: Very helpful explanation! Typically I would leave the domain blank when there are no domain restrictions. I usually only use Binary and NonNegativeReals, but I saw that RealSet popped up as an option as I was typing so I had used that just for thoroughness (as a sort of built in comment about what the variable represented).